# Map opaque section of image

Tags: html, css, image, png, transparency

I was wondering how one would go about automatically making an image map based on just the opaque parts of a png image. You are normally able to click anywhere on the png image, even transparent areas, and it will register as clicking the image. Is there any way to exclude transparent areas and only have opaque areas register?

I assume there is some sort of javascript color detection feature, or something along those lines. I have access to jQuery on my website, as well.

Thank you for taking time to read and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this with images will be a major headache. It's possible that there is a javascript library out there to detect colors, but that's very complex stuff.

Maybe give svg a go if the graphics are simple.

This [site](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/interactive-svg-map) (not mine) has a nice map using svg.